# Way to deduce if type is from a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, types

I've been trying to answer the question in the title, but I'm stumped. Basically, trying to see if there's a built-in way to tell the 'source' of a template instantiation, at least for classes. Here is an example of what I'd like to do:

```
template<class T>
class A { };

auto a = A<int>();

template<class T>
auto someFunction(T item) {
    if(/* if type of a is from the templated class A */) {
        // yep A<int> is 'from' A.
    }
}
```

Is this possible, in some way such as this? I could use some saved value or inheritance shenanigans to get something similar, but I'd rather not.

Comment: just `A<T>`, or any `C<Ts...>` or also `std::array<T, N>` ?

Comment: Do you want to detect `struct Der : A<int> {}` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 just any `A<T>`s, but nothing else. So, excluding your next two examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe with a custom type traits.

Something as follows

```
template <typename>
struct is_A : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T>
struct is_A<A<T>> : public std::true_type
 { };

// ...

template <typename T>
auto someFunction(T item) {
   if( is_A<T>::value ) {
    // yep A<int> is 'from' A.
   }
}
```

Or, maybe, you want intercept non only `A<T>` but, generically, all types that are a template type, maybe with an undefined number of template arguments?

In this case you can try with something as follows

```
template <typename>
struct is_template : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ... Ts>
struct is_template<C<Ts...>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

Problem: this type traits intercepts all template types with types template arguments and *only* template arguments. But doesn't intercept, by example, `std::integer_sequence<int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5>` that receive a type and some non-type template parameter.

You can add other specializations for `is_template`, to intercept other cases, but you can't define a specialization that catch all template types (all combinations of template parameters).

Comment: Note that this violates LSP; make `A` final if you do this.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - ehmmm... sorry, I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Ah.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle -- that a derived type can be substituted for its parent.  If `A<int>` is non-final, and B derives from `A<int>`, your code will behave differently if passed `A<int>` than `B`.  Hence violates LSP.

Comment: @max66 I believe this LSP substitution violation could be solved if the template used `std::condition` to determine if it inherited from `true_type` or `false_type`, instead of using specialization.

Answer (score 1):

Use a type trait

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class A { };

auto a = A<int>();

template <typename X>
struct is_from_A : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_from_A<A<T>> : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    std::cout << is_from_A<int>::value << "\n";     // 0
    std::cout << is_from_A<A<int>>::value << "\n";  // 1
}
```

Comment: Lovely! Thank you. What is the name of the syntax in the line `struct is_from_A<A<T>> : ...`? I thought template specializations could only use explicit values, i.e. `is_from_A<A<int>> : ...`, but apparently this is not the case.

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa: And so it is *partial specialization* (not available for function BTW).

Answer (score 1):

An other way, allowing derived class to match:

```
template <typename T>
std::true_type is_an_A_impl(A<T>*);

std::false_type is_an_A_impl(...);

template <typename T>
using is_a_A = decltype(is_an_A_impl(std::declval<T*>()));
```